# Erro: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ios, ionic, apache-cordova, angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando Cordova + Ionic + Angular, porém estou com o seguinte problema. De uma hora pra outra começou dar o seguinte erro no Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at Object. (ngx-echarts.js:162)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cc523015242fafcdd7ed:54)
>       at Object.650 (main.ts:7)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cc523015242fafcdd7ed:54)
>       at Object.645 (main.js:2673)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cc523015242fafcdd7ed:54)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap cc523015242fafcdd7ed:25)
>       at main.js:1

No SAFARI o mesmo erro é exibido desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo inspecionar elemento no *browser*, da pra perceber que esse erro é no arquivo **ngx-echarts.js** linha 162. Este arquivo faz parte de um plugin de gráficos, o [ngx-echarts](https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/home). A compilação na plataforma Android esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém este problema esta acontecendo IOS. Como gera um erro na compilação, não consigo nem instalar o app no dispositivo.

Essas são minhas configurações:

> - Ionic Framework: ^3.7.0
> - Ionic Native: ^2.9.0
> - Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.9
> - Angular Core: ^4.4.3
> - Angular Compiler CLI: ^4.4.3 Node: 8.9.3 OS
> - Platform: macOS High Sierra Navigator
> - Platform: MacIntel
> - User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75
>     Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1

Alguém já passou por esse problema? Sabe se isso é um *bug* ou algo parecido? Como posso estar resolvendo?

Comment: Tentou finalizar o server e limpar a pasta "www" (que é gerada automaticamente)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de fazer isso, porém nada. =/

Comment: Como você adicionou o `ngx-echarts`? Instalou `npm install echarts --save` e `npm install ngx-echarts --save`? Adicionou no `imports: [...]` o modulo `NgxEchartsModule`? Adicionou o echarts no `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ echarts: "echarts",...` ?

Comment: Somente o `new webpack` das suas perguntas eu não fiz, pois não encontrei o arquivo para adicionar esse trecho de código. Você tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas creio que possa criar um `webpack.config.js` na pasta root do seu projeto. Ando meio por fora de webpack, vou tentar algo para ver se consigo lhe ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento encontrei esse arquivo ` webpack.config.js` dentro de `@ionic/app-script/config/webpack.config.js`, ai adicionei em plugins, porem na documentação do link que enviei falar para adicionar no arquivo `webpack.common.js `. O engraçado é que no Android não precisou dessa configuração. Só o MAC está com essa frescura.

Comment: Eu tinha quase certeza que ao executar o comando NPM ele adicionava isto sozinho, então o common é o que será "copiado" a todos se eu não me engano, o config é do projeto. Mas não tenho certeza. Tenho que olhar melhor a doc do Angular para ter certeza se não me confundi

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então! Pra mim esse arquivo deveria estar lá, mas não esta. Quando puder olhar, me de um toque. Tenho que resolver isso logo. affe =/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei e adicionei o erro que aparece no SAFARI

Comment: Poxa, esta parecendo um BUG ou falta de update, não sei dizer se é do npm ou do webpack.